# Perform search with return key in GUI

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to get a jTextField to perform a search when I use the enter key. The searchButton does the search, so I need the action of a key press in the text field to trigger the searchButton's action.

Here's what I have just now, "Enter Pressed" is displayed on the console, when I press enter in the text field.

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    SearchButton.getActionForKeyStroke(
      KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, false));
    System.out.println("Enter Pressed");
  }
};

KeyStroke keystroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, false);
jTextField1.registerKeyboardAction(actionListener, keystroke, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just re-use the same ActionListener for both the textfield and the button?

Or, if you don't have access to the button's listener, you could just do this:

```
jTextField1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
  {
    searchButton.doClick();
  }
}
```

Comment: Or preferably, define an `Action` and add it to both the button and text field.